# Force windows xp to log into another user account on boot

Tags: windows-xp, kiosk

A kiosk pc we have at work had some trial kiosk software by kioware (http://www.kioware.com) installed on it. The pc was setup to boot into a windows xp account running this software and the software locks down the computer completely only allowing you to reboot the machine. This software’s trial period has now expired and I need to be able to get into the administrator windows account in order to register this software.

Before the kiosk software expired I could switch user accounts under windows, however now all I can do is reeboot and the software just shows a trial period expied message. The computer was setup to boot straight into the kiosk user account.

There is another user account on the pc which has full administrator access. How can I force this machine to boot into the other windows xp administrator user account setup on this computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised you could still hit Alt-F4 in the kiosk software to log off to the other Windows Xp account even though the software had expired.